# Unable to restart Hue in EMR

Tags: hadoop, emr, hue

I am unable to restart Hue in AWS EMR Hadoop cluster. 
I have modified hue.ini file and wanted to restart hue for the changes to apply.When I ran "service hue restart", It is giving "command not found" error. I can understand that this must be because hue is not added to the environment path. However, when I run bin/hue, it doesn't take restart as an input. Is there a way to restart hue?

I am using Hue 3.7.1-amzn-7, emr-4.8.4 and Amazon 2.7.3 Hadoop distribution.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The restart process depends on the EMR AMI version you are using.

**On EMR 4.x.x & 5.x.x AMI's ,**

Service management is handled by *upstart*, and not the traditional *SysVInit* scripts. So, the error like "Command not found" is expected.  Services can be queried using the upstart commands found in upstart cookbook

**List of services on EMR:**

```
grep -ir "env DAEMON=" /etc/init/ | cut -d"\"" -f2

hadoop-yarn-resourcemanager
oozie
hadoop-hdfs-namenode
hive-hcatalog-server
hadoop-mapreduce-historyserver
hue
hadoop-kms
hadoop-yarn-proxyserver
hadoop-httpfs
hive-server2
hadoop-yarn-timelineserver
```

**Example commands to stop/start hue:**

```
status hue
sudo stop hue
sudo start hue
sudo reload hue
```

---

On EMR 3.x.x AMI's ,the SysVInit commands that you are trying to use `service hue restart` might work.