# Unable to restart Hue in AWS EMR cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-emr, hue

I have an EMR Cluster in AWS, configured in a Cloudformation template. In my template, I have a step that executes a script on the master node. The purpose of this script is to make changes to the hue.ini file.
The final step in the script is to restart Hue, for the changes to take effect. I'm following [this](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/restart-service-emr/) documentation for the correct command. This documentation is explicit with **Do Not run restart**.

Running `sudo systemctl stop hue` followed by `sudo systemctl start hue` leaves Hue in the following state (per `sudo systemctl status hue`):

```
[root@ip-10-x-xxx-xxx ~]# sudo systemctl status hue
● hue.service - Hue web server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/hue.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2021-05-19 18:44:27 UTC; 2s ago
  Process: 22743 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/hue start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 17508 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
    Tasks: 0
   Memory: 0B
   CGroup: /system.slice/hue.service

May 19 18:44:27 ip-10-x-xxx-xxx systemd[1]: Failed to start Hue web server.
May 19 18:44:27 ip-10-x-xxx-xxx systemd[1]: Unit hue.service entered failed state.
May 19 18:44:27 ip-10-x-xxx-xxx systemd[1]: hue.service failed.
```

Running start again manually on the instance returns this:

```
Job for hue.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status hue.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

Those logs just show the same as above. I have also checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43718251/unable-to-restart-hue-in-emr) similar question but the answer does not work for me.

EMR: emr-6.2.0
Hue: 4.8.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a little more research, it seems this is not the best approach. The best approach is to include a `hue-ini` Classification lock in my Cloudformation template. This applies the changes and performs the required restart for you.